# Attach Reserved IP as VIP in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

finally I have my reserved static ip addresss in GCE. After that I made the haproxy and keepalived configurations, so at the moment I have 2 instances with external and internal ips, and the reserverd IP to build the VIP with keepalived.
I saw is not possible attach the same IP at differents instances, so I can imagine to make it work the keepalived I need to add en in the default network a new route rule.

I tried all possible ways but not success....

In the google doc web I didn't find anything, someone has a website with more information or any howto?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Layer 3 load balancing is available through the [Early Access Program](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/early_access). It sounds like it would do what you want.